# Which way Curve Circle’s normal and tangent point?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Does Curve Circle’s Normal point to the next point on the circle?
In this simple example, I aligned Z to the Normal of the Curve Circle but the result is quite different from my understanding. Why it is pointing outward, not tangent to the curve?
I am using Blender 3.4.1.
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: I don't get it... why do you want the normal to be tangent to the curve?

Comment: @lemon But pointing to the next point on the curve isn't tangent...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, this is nearly the same question...

Comment: @lemon That's just a misunderstanding of the OP on what a normal is. But if the actual question here is how to align something with the tangent and it is believed that it points to the next point on the curve, then this is another misunderstanding and makes a difference in how to align an object to that vector.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, I agree. Quan Lee, could you clarify, please?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you all for the help! Now I understand the arrows are not a normal indication of a curve. It is merely showing the direction and the tilting of the curve. Thanks!

Comment: @QuanLee That's not quite correct. In your screenshot the blue arrows **are** a normal indication, they **are** pointing in direction of the curve normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. Just like mesh curve, the tangent is tangent to the circle, but unlike mesh curve normals direct outward from the origin, curve circles' normals are affected by the tilting of the curve section.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! Now I understand it!